# Problem using ${RunningX64} in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I am using the code below in several parts of my script.

```
${If} ${RunningX64}
; 64bit bits go here
${Else}
; 32bit bits go here
${EndIf}
```

In one function it runs perfectly fine, but the other calls will not work unless they are used after the initial call that executed correctly.

I have not been able to find any logical reason for this behavior. I have included both the LogicLib.nsh and x64.nsh heather files, but it goes through the 64 bit section.

What could it be? There does not seem to be any macros to initialize prior their use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using GetVersion plugin this way:

```
Var WINDOWS_ARCHITECTURE

GetVersion::WindowsPlatformArchitecture
Pop $WINDOWS_ARCHITECTURE ; 32 or 64
```

Comment: **Attention:** GetVersion Plugin is discontinued.